# Identity server 4 custom login

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

We don't want to use login page provided by identity server but want to build custom login pages in plain html and javascript and webapi.

is there any way to do this please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your will pass the users identity for other services provider use OpenID or Oauth.
If is just a local login, i dont understant your question. Just create a simple database where you store users-pass, create the login layout and check if users-pass check (can use php).

Comment: I think he just wants to modify the look of the login page.

Comment: That's correct @moritzg.also i don't wish to use cshtml

Comment: @Razor Why not cshtml? You can use it like html and use javascript too.

Comment: @Razor does not want to use Razor?

Comment: @leastprivilege I like what you did there